# webmail postfix Maildir via netapp is very slow

Tags: postfix, netapp, webmail, squirrelmail

I have postfix+courier mail server and I am using squirrelmail as webmail in another server. maildir dirs are in netapp server on fc disks. There is not other speed problem with other servers that using netapp. but my squirrelmail web page is very slow to list mails in imap protocol. what should I do? 
I also used roundcube but result is same

Answer (score 2):

Remove courier and replace it with dovecot. The advanced indexing and caching mechanisms in dovecot outpaces everything else.
If you have mounted the Maildirs via NFS from the netapp then you have to work around the NFS issues (http://wiki2.dovecot.org/NFS)